# Shell on my Vagrant box is slower than it should be

Tags: virtualbox, shell, virtualization, vagrant

The shell on my vagrant box is incredibly slow, atleast at some things. For instance, if I press enter with nothing typed in, it takes about 3-5 seconds for it to be ready to take another command. This should be 0 to nearly 0 on most machines.

This is my second vagrant box after my first one was rendered unusable somehow (i forget) and I had to recreate it. However I dont remember it being this slow.

When I hit enter I can see 1 of my CPUs hit or come close to 100% and then come down before it is ready to accept input.

Disclaimer, I am using a P4 so I dont expect it to be super snappy but I expect it to be 80-90% of the host OS (Linux Mint 15) which it is not able to maintain.

Comment: seems to be because of my Bashrc stuff, If i move out of a git folder(I use lot of git status detection stuff) it goes up to what I see in the host system, and in `sudo -i` it is virtually 0

Comment: Enter `set -x` and watch what's happening.

Comment: @glennjackman ah interesting, havent come across that one before.. I see a `git diff` at which the terminal hangs a bit.. I think my `__git_ps1` uses that if dirty state is enabled